# Interjection after completing a difficult task

Tags: interjections

What interjection a native English speaker might use after completing a difficult task? Something like "oof", "ooh", etc.

> ______! It's been a tough day!
>
> ______! Running a marathon is not easy!
>
> ______! I think I've finally solved this puzzle

Comment: "Phew" is one of those expressions used after a difficult situation is over.

Comment: I often say 'Holy Jesus!' or 'By Saint Loy!', or something much more vulgar. Just about any vehement exclamation will do. Any answer is bound to be opinion-based. A child or elderly religious lady might say 'oof', or 'ooh', etc.

Comment: If we're talking about instinctive 'noises' rather than expletives, I agree with Yunus that _Phew!_ fits the bill. It represents a sharp exhalation of breath and expresses relief that something bad is over (or didn't happen as expected).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes curiously, I've never heard anyone say, "Oh, Buddha!" or "Blessed Mohammed!" I wonder why not. :-)

Comment: @Jay - the founder of the Rinzai sect of Zen Buddhism, Linji Yixuan, was once asked what 'the true person with no rank' (the enlightened mind) was. He replied, “What a shit-wiping stick!”. Many Muslims say 'Wallahi (by Allah) this' or 'Wallahi that' in casual conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Phew" (mentioned in a comment above) is probably the most common interjection for such a situation. [M-W says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phew) that it is "used to express relief or fatigue". [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries says](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/phew) that it can show that someone is "happy that something bad has finished" and gives this example:

> "Phew, I'm glad that's all over."

Other interjections are also possible but are more commonly used for other purposes. For example, "oh", "Jesus", and "wow" are frequently used to express shock or surprise. ("Oh" can also indicate pain or distress, as in "oh, my back!", which might be appropriate after some difficult tasks.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible words. "Phew", "Wow", "Oh", many others. Almost any obscenity would fit.